# add element before some element

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
<td>
    <div id="vB_Editor_QR_cmd_email" class="imagebutton">
      abc
    </div>
</td>
```

I want put another element to this code like this:

```
<p>blablablalblablab</p>
 <td>
    <div id="vB_Editor_QR_cmd_email" class="imagebutton">
       abc
     </div>
 </td>
```

I use this code

```
 $("#vB_Editor_QR_cmd_insertimage").before("<p>blablablalblablab</p>");
```

but it only put before div tag.

```
 <td>
    <p>blablablalblablab</p>
    <div id="vB_Editor_QR_cmd_email" class="imagebutton">
       abc
     </div>
 </td>
```

I want it like this

```
 <p>blablablalblablab</p>
     <td>
        <div id="vB_Editor_QR_cmd_email" class="imagebutton">
           abc
         </div>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#vB_Editor_QR_cmd_insertimage").parents("td:first").before("<p>blablablalblablab</p>");
```

parents("td:first") will return first parent of div

hope this help.....

Answer (score 7):

Use [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) to place an element before another.

```
$("<p>blablablalblablab</p>").insertBefore("td");
```

or

```
$("td").insertBefore("<p>blablablalblablab</p>");
```

or more specifical to your html:

```
$("vB_Editor_QR_cmd_email").parent("td").before(...);
```

Though unless this is just a (bad) example, this is invalid.  You can't have a `<p>` tag directly before a `<td>` because that would imply that the `<p>` is within a `<tr>`.

Comment: oh no $("<p>blablablalblablab</p>") can be change and in code have very much td tag. only <div id="vB_Editor_QR_cmd_email" class="imagebutton"> tag is fixed

Answer (score 1):

This selects the td element that has a nested div with an id of vB_Editor_QR_cmd_insertimage.  It also provides a cleaner way to create an html element (that jQuery provides)

```
$("div#vB_Editor_QR_cmd_insertimage").closest("td")
.before($("<p/>", { text: "blablablalblablab" }));
```

Comment: That doesn't do what you say it does.  It selects the div, not the td.

Comment: Good catch.  I am now using closest() to go up the DOM tree to grab the td element.