# How to append a dropdown list before a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I have a div that holds a dropdown list of items. I want the user to add more dropdown list's by pressing a button.

I managed this, but the problem I'm facing is that the new list gets appended after the button. I want the button to be always underneath the dropdown list.

I know that there is an option called insertBefore(), but I don't really know how to use it correctly in my case.

Oh and by the way, do you guys have any thoughts about how to give each new dropdown list a unique name? Because it is a form that I am planning on sending later on. I think I need to work with counters in my script file, but I om not sure yet.

So the HTML:

```
<form role="form" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      ..not important for the question...
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="controls" id="dropdown_item">
            <select class="offerte_product" name="product_1">
                 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
                 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
             </select>

             <input id="add_option" type="submit" value="Add More" onclick="return false" />
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      ..not important for the question...
     </div>
```

And the script I am using is:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#add_option').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<select class="offerte_product" name="product_2"> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> </select> ');
        $("#dropdown_item").append(r);
    });
});
```

So do I need to put insertBefore somewhere before the append(r)? I really have no clue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add element before some element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475489/add-element-before-some-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the button outside the `div`:

```
<div class="controls" id="dropdown_item">
    <select class="offerte_product" name="product_1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="add_option" type="submit" value="Add More" onclick="return false" />
```

You can keep appending to the `div` and the button will still be below it.

Comment: lol, I guess tunnelvision can really screw you up.. Thanks! Any thoughts about the unique name value? I want something like: product_1, product_2 etc.. Do you think a counter will work?

Comment: @Mirwais: A counter could do the trick.  Depends on how this data eventually gets used.  If it's a form posting to the server, making an array (`name="product[]"`) might work well too.  If it's only bring processed client-side then the `name` attribute might not even be as relevant.

Comment: Yes, it is a form posting to the server. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I created fiddle for this question.You can create different name according to product group ID.

```
$(function(){
        var productGroupID=1;
        $('#add_option').on('click',function(){
                productGroupID+=1;
            var r= $('<select class="offerte_product" name=product_'+productGroupID+'> <option value="volvo">Volvo</option> </select> ');
            $("#dropdown_item").append(r);
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypaudyal/15jt7tLf/

But If you are posting to the server, I suggest you to use same name and collect the selected values in collection.