# jQuery prepend on clone inserting at unexpected location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to copy the contents of a DIV and insert a heading before the copy. However, the heading gets inserted at the wrong point.

```js
var reference = $('#reference').clone().contents();
reference.prepend('<h1>Heading</h1>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reference">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the heading to go before the `<ul>` but instead it gets inserted after before the first `li`.

So it looks like this:

```
<div id="copy">
  <ul>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of this (what I want):

```
<div id="copy">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is probably a really basic question but a few hours of trying `prependTo()`, `before()`, `insertBefore()` and searching online have not gotten me any closer. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add element before some element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475489/add-element-before-some-element)

Comment: maybe something like this? var reference = $('#reference > ul').clone().contents();

Comment: try using- `$('#reference').clone().contents().parent().prepend('<h1>Heading</h1>')`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly remove `contents()` as you want to clone the whole element, not its children. Secondly, create the `h1` tag, then use `prependTo()` to place it at the desired location in the cloned element.

Also note that your current code results in duplicate `id` attributes in the DOM, which is invalid. I'd suggest making the `#reference` id in to a class instead. Try this:

```js
var reference = $('.reference:first').clone();
$('<h1>Heading</h1>').prependTo(reference);

$('body').append(reference);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reference">
  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response! I made a few mistakes in my original question - I did actually only want the contents of `#reference` and using `prependTo()` still results in the heading being inserted after the `<ul>`. I've edited and corrected my original question

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what you want. Can you edit the question to show the HTML you expect to have after the jQuery has run *including the cloned content*

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this I have tried and It is working fine.

`$('#reference').clone().contents().parent().prepend('<h1>Hea‌​ding</h1>')`

Comment: This actually does exactly what I needed to do. Thanks! :o)